# Retrieve last output from JSON file on URL

Tags: json

I have a temperature & humidity monitoring system (Watchdog v3.3) which is dumping the last three months of data to `IP-address/log.json`.

I can download the whole file with:

```
 wget 'http://IP-address/log.json' log.json
```

which saves a file `log.json` in whichever directory I was.

Once there, I can rad the latest value with:

```
cat log.json | jq. '.data[.data | length -1]'
```

For completeness, the JSON file looks like this:
[image]

The data is stored in `data` with one new entry every minute.

--

The file is 3.3 MB because it's downloading three months worth of data. Ideally I would just donwload the latest one, and just append it to a file on my computer. 
 **How do I just download the latest entry on the online JSON file ?**

(Eventually I will combine this with `crontabs` on Linux in order to query the URL every so often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't, I don't think. You can either request the resource at that URL and download it, or you can not make the request.

This is because until the request has completed and you have fetched all the data, there's no way to parse it and understand which bit is the "last" entry. Your computer cannot read what is on the remote server without fully downloading it via HTTP first (that's actually what happens every time you "view" a webpage - in reality it's downloaded to your machine and displayed in your browser). And it cannot try to download only part of the document, because in this case that partial download would consist of invalid and incomplete JSON which it would be unable to comprehend.

The solution would be for the server to expose a method by which you could request which part of the log you want to see, but from what you've said it looks like it's just giving you access to a static file (albeit one which is frequently updated) rather than an endpoint which runs some code to query the data. Perhaps the product you're using does actually offer this kind of thing via another API call?

Having said all that 3.3MB is not a lot of data in today's world (unless you have got a very slow or cheap internet connection - but it sounds like you're not doing this via a mobile device, which would be more likely to have data caps or speed issues). Consider how frequently you need to update this information. Is it worth going to the trouble of trying to request snippets of it? Or can you simply be content to over-write what you've got at regular - but not too regular - intervals?

Comment: Is there a way to only download the last KB of data or so?

Comment: No. As I explained above, when you make a HTTP request, you automatically receive the whole response. Nothing more and nothing less. The only way round this is if the server itself provides a different HTTP endpoint where you can request specific logical parts of the log file, and it provides you that as a different response.